# Why did all of my items disappear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So today I logged onto my minecraft singleplayer world and all my items (including my armour and chest items) disappeared.  The weirdest thing was all my item frames were knocked off the walls, the chests were still there (just empty), and all the signs said really weird stuff.  Here's one example:

> null
>   "dyes and
>   dye ingredients"
>   null

What's going on?

Comment: This has happened to me before, it sounds like you have opened the world in one version , and then opened the same world in an older version, corrupting it somewhat.

Comment: Herobrian.................................

Comment: likely duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172670/what-happened-to-my-minecraft-world. @DClevels: Did you open that world in a snapshot and reverted to an older version?

Comment: yes i  but i went strait back to 1.7.1 after

Comment: Basically, you're hosed. Whenever you update to a newer version (especially snapshots) always always always make backups of your saved worlds. You might want to back up your entire .minecraft folder to be even safer.

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider marking it correct. Click the check mark button underneath the vote count.

Comment: This, my friends, is why you **back up .minecraft before using snapshots**.

Comment: Or Herobrine was there.

Comment: I know it was null because of the sign.

Answer (score 8):

This has happened to me. When you open a world in 1.8 (or any post-1.7 snapshot), it changes the way the data is stored (tile entities, blocks and inventory data). This means, for example (using Torches): `50` becomes `minecraft:torch`.

When you open the world back in 1.7, Minecraft goes "What the heck are these?" (`minecraft:torch`) and therefore deletes it, as it is not recognized as a block/item/whatever. From there, you would find blocks such as signs/chests (item with TileEntity data) and items in your inventory missing.

---

The only way you can get your world back is to restore a backup (if you have one), like I did.
If you don't have one, then you'll have to start all over again, as there is no going back once you've opened the save. But if you have a windows 7 profesional you can restore an older version of the file.

Comment: Seriously, why doesn't it warn you that this might happen?

Comment: It does, actually. When you check "Enable experimental development builds" in the launcher, it says "Are you sure you want to enable development builds? They are not guaranteed to be stable and MAY CORRUPT YOUR WORLDS" (emphasis added)

Comment: I was on 1.7.10 and moved to 1.8.1 (then back to 1.7.10). Neither of those are experimental builds.

Comment: Well, my mistake then. I would then expect Mojang to make some form of announcement (which they probably did, and I missed because I never check mojang.com).

Comment: I'd just take a "you're loading a savefile from a newer version. This may cause loss of blah blah blah"...

Comment: Maybe submit the idea to Mojang. I'm sure they'd add it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when 1 of 3 things happen:

1. Downloading a Mod and then removing it. Items from the mod including tables/chairs (or whatever the mod is about) will dissappear allong with some items.
2. Going from a newer version to an older version. This corrupts the file because the newer items no longer exist and are therefore nulled.
3. Going from an older modded game to a newer modded game. The mods are out of date so the items will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

updating from 1.6.4 to 1.7 will cause that, it was updating from 1.7 to 1.8, downgrading from 1.8 to 1.7, or downgrading from 1.7 to 1.6.4. if you did any of those things, too bad. changing the version back will do no effect. the only way to solve this problem (that I found) is to use an backup. otherwise, sorry.