# Porting vanilla Minecraft server map to spigot does not port inventories

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

We currently have a vanilla Minecraft server that we want to upgrade to a Spigot server. I have got all of the infrastructure set up, and copied over the world map. So far so good, and the terrain, XP levels and player positions are correctly updated. However, all chest, furnace and inventory content have been wiped.

Online there are almost no sources covering this subject. So I was wondering if there is anyone who has any experience with doing this the correct way.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the way data is stored. Just a question: What is the version of the vanilla server that you took the world from and what is the spigot's Minecraft version?

Comment: The Minecraft server used is 1.8 and the Spigot version used is build #1649. Which as I gathered support MC version 1.8 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely, you've faced the same problem as this guy:
[What happened to my minecraft world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172670/what-happened-to-my-minecraft-world)

---

The problem is that you're trying to bring a post-1.7-snapshot or 1.8 world back into 1.7.10, Minecraft isn't able to read the stored data as they have been converted into named items rather than numerical IDs.

For example, `50` (for Torches) become `minecraft:Torch`.
Because 1.7 and any earlier releases/snapshots don't read items by their names but instead by their integer IDs, it automatically deletes them as they are considered to be incompatible objects.
*A string is NOT a integer: For example, "ONE" is not a number; it's a word, whereas "1" is a number.*

As for why XP and player position remained; it is because there have been no changes to the way this data is stored. Only item/block-related information has been changed.

---

As for fixing, it - There isn't actually a way. Unless you don't mind going through all NBT data and changing the names back into IDs.
*As per current, there are numerous programs (and mods) that allow you to edit NBT data, but there isn't any that allows you to mass-edit them.*

Otherwise, stick with Vanilla; it has more 'stuff' than the current Spigot version.
(The Spigot version only allows 1.8 players to connect, but 1.8 items such as armor stands and commands do not exist)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will stick with the vanilla server for now then.